# How can I round a C# double nullable type?

Tags: c#

I want to round a `double?` value so that if its value is 2.3 the result should be 2 but if the input is null then the result should be null.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is no direct way to round a nullable double. You need to check if the variable has a value: if yes, round it; otherwise, return `null`.

You need to cast a bit if you do this using the conditional `?:` operator:

```
double? result = myNullableDouble.HasValue
               ? (double?)Math.Round(myNullableDouble.Value)
               : null;
```

Alternatively:

```
double? result = null;
if (myNullableDouble.HasValue)
{
    result = Math.Round(myNullableDouble.Value);
}
```

Comment: well both @dtb and @Eric Lippert answers are great, but I am wondering which i should marked as correct answer. @dtb has lower reputation  so his answer would be marked as the correct one:D. But @Eric your solution is really great too. Thanks you both. By the way, this method should be added to .net 5, is there any list here where we can add what shoudl be added to another .net freamework?

Comment: @kosnkov, don't base the acceptance on whose rep is higher or lower, base it on whose answer solved your problem the best. Did you go with dtb's approach or create a method like Eric? We're not about balancing the scales here, we're about objectively identifying the answer that solved the specific problem. However, in the case of two *identical* answers, I would suggest using submission time as the tiebreaker, but that's just me.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram, mate listen, if both are great answers what can I do? or as u said time submission or whatever else, it is very hard in that case to decide which one is better.

Answer (score 26):

As others have pointed out, it is easy enough to do this as a one-off. To do it in general:

```
static Func<T?, T?> LiftToNullable<T>(Func<T, T> func) where T : struct
{
    return n=> n == null ? (T?) null : (T?) func(n.Value);
}
```

And now you can say:

```
var NullableRound = LiftToNullable<double>(Math.Round);
double? d = NullableRound(null);
```

And hey, now you can do this with *any* method that takes and returns a value type.

Answer (score 3):

```
return d.HasValue ? Math.Round(d.Value) : (double?)null;
```

Comment: Close, but not quite. Put a cast to (double?) on the null to fix it.